# Can a 3x20(80A) energy meter handle 22kW (3x32A)?

Tags: electrical

I'm installing a 22kW EV charger that draws 3x32A and I want to have an energy meter to see how much the cars are using. The energy meter I was told was ok is a [B+G DRT428DC-V3](https://bg-etech.de/download/manual/DRT428DC-MID.pdf), but now when I'm about to install it I'm doubting that is correct.

[image]

It says 3x20(80A) on the front. I've been told that it means that each phase should be able to handle 80A, so in total 240A, which should be more than enough to cover the total of 96A that I need.

However, the big question I have is whether the 80A is per phase or the combined maximum of the three phases?

Is the 3x20(80A) energy meter powerful enough to handle 22kW (3x32A)?

Comment: Please link to the datasheet (and definitely not to an Amazon ad or similar).

Comment: You should check the datasheet, manual or contact the manufacturer. This is not something to trifle with and you should  only trust a verifiable source for the information. A quick check on Google shows that the rated current is 20 amps and the limit current (not sure what that is) is 80 amps. I suspect that this unit is not up to your requirements.

Comment: I agree about the datasheet and manufacturer and I'm not taking this lightly, that is why I'm asking. The manufacturer does not have a support and the datasheet does not say if it is one or all phases. https://xn--stromzhler-v5a.eu/stromzaehler/drehstromzaehler/fuer-hutschiene-ungeeicht/13/drt428dc-v2-3-phasen-drehstromzaehler-mit-s0-auf-4-2te

Answer (score 2):

The 20A rating is the **basic current** as defined in IEC 61036.
This is the nominal value for the other specifications, this is valid up to the maximum 80A.

Outside those limit increases the error.

Comment: So 3x32A a 3-4 hours continuously a day should be ok?

Comment: ~%50 overload is a lot for 3-4 hours.  You should refer to the datasheet or contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @32kW See it like this: the maximum circuit breaker rating is 20A.

Comment: @Jeroen3 - but is that the way it should be read? Others have 3x20(120)A, so what's the point of the 80 or 120 if the limit is 20 for both? I can not seem to find energy meter with 3x32 or 3x40 or higher, that is why I ask the question.

Comment: @32kW I looking into it a bit more. And it's an IEC thing. The meter works within spec up to 80A. See edit. Nothing thermal or maximum rating.

Answer (score 2):

I've received answer back from the manufacturer.

'yes, you can use the device with a 22kW wallbox. The device can work with continuous loads of up to 80A per phase, so there is still enough space above.'